# Automatically Refresh an 'app.get()' in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, refresh, reload

I tried to find this topic everywhere, unsuccessfully.

I have a app.get() code, really simple, that gets one information from a variable that is constantly changing ("equip[id].status"), I want it to check if the variable changed from time to time.

Other option is keep a track on this variable, and when it changes run app.get() again.

My codes:

This is the one I want to refresh:

```
app1.get("/", function(req,res){
    id = 1;
    res.render(__dirname + '/connected.html', {equipment: 'Esteira 1', status: equip[id].status, historico: equip[id].hist});
});
```

And this are the ones that change "status"

```
app1.get("/open", function(req,res){
    id = 1;
    equip[id].status = 'Conectado';
    equip[id].hist = equip[id].hist + equip[id].status;
    var now = new Date();
    time = dateFormat(now,"h:MM:ss");
    console.log(time+" - Equipment 'Esteira 1' has connected on port 3001");
    res.end
    });


app1.get("/closed", function(req,res){
    id = 1;
    equip[id].status = 'Desconectado';
    equip[id].hist = equip[id].hist + equip[id].status;
    var now = new Date();
    time = dateFormat(now,"h:MM:ss");
    console.log(time+" - Equipment 'Esteira 1' has disconnected");
    res.end
    });
```

Comment: Not clear what you're asking for help with or trying to accomplish or where the `equip` variable comes from.

Comment: So, this is actually a program for my university, it doesn't have an easy way to explain the whole thing. 

But what I want is: Every time a person clicks in a button and `connect` the device I write it in the status, and everytime they click in the other button they `disconnect`, and I also write this in the status. While this, I have this page that is opened in the `localhost:port/`, in the first time I open it, it works perfectly, but I change the `status` and then I need to manually refresh the page, I want to do this automatically from time to time. (Hope now it's more clear)

Comment: The `equip` variable is just a normal matrix variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `app.get()` is a server-side code, and on it's own it has no power over changing the client-side.

In the client-side, you need to employ a javascript code to either poll the server regularly (ajax) or have it actively listen to server for changes through websockets. That way you can also choose to either refresh the whole page or just load the relevant changes (like this very site does!).

You should look into these relevant technologies: javascript, ajax, long-polling, socket.io